# How to create a Empty dataframe in sparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

In R, `df_new <- data.frame()` creates a empty dataframe,
In the same way can we create empty data frame in sparkR

I tried creating empty dataframe in R and convert it into sparkR dataframe,
`df_sparkR <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df_new)`, but its throws error cannot infer from null.

TIA,
Arun

Comment: You can create an empty data frame with specific schema `createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(k=character(), v=integer()))` , but I doubt it is possible to create completely empty data frame without going through Java API calls. As far as I can tell R `structType`  cannot be used with `NULL`, and this is the standard way of creating empty data frames. BTW I am curious - what is the use case here?

Comment: why do you need to create an empty df?

Comment: In scala api, we have `sqlContext.emptyDataFrame`

Comment: One use case I found an Empty DataFrame is useful is that I have a data set saved in HDFS which consists of 10 .csv files. In order to read all of them into SparkR, I need to loop over those 10 .csv file. Each loop `read.df` a single `.csv` file. So I need an empty DataFrame to piece together all 10 smaller DataFrames.